# Is it possible to focus on an 'input' tag that is a child of an element rendered by 'v-if'?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, vue.js, focus

Say I have the following vue.js template code:

```
<div v-if="x===0">
  <input ref="text">{{text}}</input>
</div>
```

Where x is some data loaded asynchronously.

How can I focus on that 'input' element after the 'if' statement has been evaluated?

Comment: Use `nextTick` with your ref.

Comment: Something like this. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/BPBvBZ?editors=1010

Answer (score 2):

Would this approach work? Here I'm [deferring](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) `this.$refs.textInput.focus()` to be executed after the next DOM update cycle  (thanks [@Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert) for reminding) so that Vue could re-render the component (i.e. it adds the input and sets the ref) and we would have the ref to call `focus()` function.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    x: 1,
    text: 'Hey'
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.x = 1 - this.x;          
    }, 1000);
  },
  watch: {
    x: {
      handler: function(value) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$refs.textInput && this.$refs.textInput.focus();
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

#app {
  background: powderblue;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="x===0">
    <input ref="textInput" v-model="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Vue, you would use `$nextTick`.

Comment: @Bert thanks, it's been a long time since I used vuejs last time, forgot about that function.

Comment: Updated my code snippet so that the component watches the value of `x` and when it changes, it would check in next tick if there's a ref called `textInput` and if it is there, it will get the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Would autofocus work?

```
<div v-if="x===0">
  <input ref="text" autofocus>{{text}}</input>
</div>
```

Comment: No unfortunately.